# Want to use my existing mysql database with django

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a django project and now rendering templates. I have a mysql database already with loads of tables and data.

From what i saw in the tutorials, the model concept of python is interesting and easy however i am not able to use it here, as i have no models available i guess. Was assuming django would magically create models based on my db.

I have filled up settings.py with engine, db, username, host, port etc.,
Do i have to create models based on my tables?

This works thou:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='dbBooks', passwd='1234', host='localhost')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT bookname FROM books')
names = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
db.close()
return render(request, 'index.html', {'bookNames': names})
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`inspectdb` works fine now. (Django 1.7.1) Simply running manage.py inspectdb will create classes for all tables in database and display on console.

```
 $ python manage.py inspectdb
```

Save this as a file by using standard Unix output redirection:

```
 $ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/)

Answer (score 6):

There is an way by which Django will auto-magically create models based on tables using the [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) option of `manage.py`. A short guide is provided in Django Documentation itself on [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the link. I've tried doing it. The call never ends. I waited for more than an hour. It is running forever. I have around ten tables and cumulatively 2500 rows. Is there a way to know if the inspectdb is working?